# Why show error in console : "No data specified" after using jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

Suppose, I have two arrays for x axis and y axis respectively. I am trying to draw line graph chart with jsPlot. I have done this:

```
 if (watervalue.length != 0) {

                        for (var a = 0; a < watervalue.length; a++) {

                            wvalues += '[' + months[watermonth[a]] + ',' + watervalue[a] + '],';
                        }
  }

                    wvalues = wvalues.slice(0, -1) + ']';
var plot2 = $.jqplot('container1', wvalues, {
                        // Give the plot a title.
                        title: 'Plot With Options',
                        // You can specify options for all axes on the plot at once with
                        // the axesDefaults object.  Here, we're using a canvas renderer
                        // to draw the axis label which allows rotated text.
                        axesDefaults: {
                            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                        },
                        // Likewise, seriesDefaults specifies default options for all
                        // series in a plot.  Options specified in seriesDefaults or
                        // axesDefaults can be overridden by individual series or
                        // axes options.
                        // Here we turn on smoothing for the line.
                        seriesDefaults: {
                            rendererOptions: {
                                smooth: true
                            }
                        },
                        // An axes object holds options for all axes.
                        // Allowable axes are xaxis, x2axis, yaxis, y2axis, y3axis, ...
                        // Up to 9 y axes are supported.
                        axes: {
                            // options for each axis are specified in seperate option objects.
                            xaxis: {
                                label: "X Axis",
                                // Turn off "padding".  This will allow data point to lie on the
                                // edges of the grid.  Default padding is 1.2 and will keep all
                                // points inside the bounds of the grid.
                                pad: 0
                            },
                            yaxis: {
                                label: "Y Axis"
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

It shows error, **No data specified**

The `console.log` output of `wvalues` is:

> [[February,0],[March,0],[April,0],[May,0],[June,0],[July,7]]

Where's the problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with 'jsPlot', but shouldn't you pass an `Array` object instead of a `string` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to [pass an `Array` instead of a `string`](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html). modify your for loop similar to follows and remove that `wvalues = wvalues.slice(0, -1) + ']';` line as well.

```js
var months = ['February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
var watervalue = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7];

var wvalues = [];
var tmp = [];

for(var i=0; i < watervalue.length; i++){

  tmp = [months[i], watervalue[i]];
  // In your case: tmp = [months[watermonth[i]], watervalue[i]]
  
  wvalues.push(tmp);

}

console.log(wvalues); 
// output: [["February",0],["March",0],["April",0],["May",0],["June",0],["July",7]]
```